# Max texture size Android : which settings for 2048x2048?

Tags: android, textures, texture-atlas

I want to use a texture atlas of 2048 x 2048 in my game, and I would like to warn the users with a "too low" device to not download the game.

With a texture atlas of this size, what requirements should I say, on ANDROID ?

This image (source : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392027/recommended-limit-for-memory-management-in-cocos2d ) shows the requirements for IPHONE, what about for ANDROID : 512Mo minimum, with a 1GHz, is a correct requirement ?

[image]

Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'll be okay to ship your game to majority of your users with a configuration like that. Even the fairly old (nearly 3 years now) old [Samsung Galaxy Captivate](http://www.glbenchmark.com/phonedetails.jsp?benchmark=glpro25&D=Samsung%20SGH-I897%20Captivate&testgroup=gl) will run with a texture resolution of that size. You won't have too many issues supporting almost any device like that (I can't think of any off the top of my head. Okay, that's a lie... maybe the [HTC Drean](http://www.glbenchmark.com/phonedetails.jsp?benchmark=glpro25&D=HTC%20Dream%20%28Google%20G1%29&testgroup=gl). However, that being said if you want to prevent random crashes and the like when a user OPENS your app - do yourself a favour and query for **GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE**. This will return the maximum texture dimension you can use and if it's less than 2048 you can throw a warning to your user stating gameplay probably won't work or you can load some alternative assets if that's possible for your game that might work for the game at a lower resolution, scale, or with some effects missing. The choice is yours!

**Edit:** We're in 2015 now; nearing 2016. You can safely assume most devices will support such an atlas.

Comment: I know this is an old question @VaughanHilts but I'm curious, you say 'or you can load some alternative assets' I'm experiencing this issue at the moment. After querying GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE and discovering that the Max size is say 2048 and you have a texture of say 3000 in your xhdpi folder and this device get its assets from that folder, how does one go about loading alternative/smaller resources? They're already there in the HDPI, MDPI and LDPI folder, but how do you tell the device to get them? Any thoughts would be appreciated! Thanks :-)

Comment: This is my question if you have any suggestions! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25796430/opengl-texture-size-limits-providing-alternate-resources-for-specific-android-d