# Do I have to keep textures in Android games smaller than 1024^2?

Tags: graphics, gpu

I have read tips in books and article that point out, if you are making a game for Android, make sure your textures are =< 1024^2, or you'll not reach all your potential customers.

I have never found a concrete statistic that proves this claim. What are we talking about, here, 5% of Android devices only support 1024? 10%? 80%?

Comment: I have done quite a bit of OpenGL ES programming, only the newer devices can handle textures larger than 1024 by 1024. All of the OpenGL ES games I have made have used a maximum of 512 just to keep lag down on older devices. I would stick to 1024 and less if I were you.

Comment: @John Interesting.. but, I really need clear statistics that can prove the viability of using a certain texture size. I have many sprites larger than 1024^2, and it'll be a pain to split them among many sheets.

Comment: This question seems very similar to http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/49963/max-texture-size-android-which-settings-for-2048x2048

Comment: @Mazyod do you know which version of Android you want to target?

Comment: @John Android with OpenGL ES 2.0, (i.e 2.3+)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take a look at these stats 
http://stats.unity3d.com/mobile/gpu.html

scroll down to gpu model 
start google ing each gpu and see max texture size for each one

i'll do the first one 
for mali 400 is 4096x4096

now assuming all drivers that have this gpu support this size you're in luck 
you already have 30% of the market

Good luck with your game.

Comment: Awesome. I continued what you started, and realized that most of these GPUs support at least 2048^2 texture sizes. No worries then!