# Are lightmaps also considered textures?

Tags: unity, textures, performance, texture-atlas, lightmap

I want my game to support phones with max texture size of 1024 so my texture atlases are 1024. My question is: are lightmaps also considered textures and their max size must be 1024? Or they can have higher dimensions like 4096?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, lightmaps are textures. [Lightmaps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightmap) are a record of the lighting value for a surface at a particular point, and the way we represent "surface data for a particular point" in modern 3D graphics is with textures.

Unity's lightmapping implementation uses [Beast](http://gameware.autodesk.com/beast). The default lightmap atlas size limit is 1024x1024. Terrain, [per the documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LightmappingInDepth.html), allows you to specify an arbitrary lightmap size. The documentation does not mention a limit, but [this thread](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/light-map-max-at-1k-solved.56435/) suggests the limit is 4096x4096.

That thread also notes that you can chance the size of *regular* lightmap atlas textures via scripting, by setting `LightmapEditorSettings.maxAtlasWidth` and `LightmapEditorSettings.maxAtlasHeight` to any value up to 4096.

However, if you are self-imposing a limit of 1024x1024 for your textures you will not want to exceed that in the setting of any lightmap sizes, because that will cause the creation of larger textures.

Comment: so if i use 4096 lightmap i wont be able to support iPhone3G , iPhone4 as [here](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/49963/max-texture-size-android-which-settings-for-2048x2048) says, right?

Comment: I believe that's true, yes. I don't think Unity will cut the lightmaps into multiple textures to fit into system limitations like that, though I could be wrong.